# Can I use DECLARE as an SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to execute a query in PHP, but this code wouldn't work for some reason, it doesn't detect the keywords at all(DECLARE, SELECT, WHERE). Is there anything I can do and after all can I even use DECLARE in PHP as a mySQLi statement.

`$sql2 ="DECLARE @MaxID INT; SELECT @MaxID = MAX(productID) FROM products; UPDATE sunglasses SET sunglassesId = @MaxID WHERE sunglassesId = 0;";`

After all I am trying to update a field in Table1 where its initial value is 0 with a value from a field in Table2.
Hope that made sense.

P.S tried this query in Microsoft SQL Management studio and it worked, in PHP it doesnt.

Comment: simply because it's not a *query* but a set of queries. Run them one by one as it's intended, and you'll be fine

Comment: @YourCommonSense I did this and the declare doesnt register as a key word but the rest do(couldnt use the at character because of some error):  $sql1 = "DECLARE MaxID INT"; 
 $sql2 = "SELECT MaxID = MAX(productID) FROM products";
 $sql3 = "UPDATE sunglasses SET sunglassesId = MaxID WHERE sunglassesId = 0";

            $sql4 = $sql1 . $sql2 . $sql3;

Comment: You have to *run* there queries separately! RUN, not just declare.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for helping Sir, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your query to this and you don't need any other variable:

```
UPDATE sunglasses 
SET sunglassesId = (SELECT MAX(productID) FROM products)
WHERE sunglassesId = 0;
```